# Sound is missing after switch to Nvidia prime mode

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, sound, intel-graphics, 19.04

I have two videocards Nvidia GTX 1050 and Intel HD. I also have a dual boot with Windows 10. When i am switch to Intel HD Graphics and reinstall alsa drivers sound is work then i switch to Nvidia mode and sound is still working but when i am restart my system sound is missing on Nvidia mode.